# Return value mapping on Stored Procedures in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, mapping

I am calling a stored procedure with EntityFramework. But custom property that i set in partial entity class is null.
I have  Entities in my edmx (I called edmx i dont know what to call for this). For example I have a "User" table in my database and so i have a "User" class on my Entity.
I have a stored procedure called GetUserById(@userId) and in this stored procedure i am writing a basic sql statement like below

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id=@userId"
```

in my edmx i make a function import to call this stored procedure and set its return value to Entities (also select User from dropdownlist). It works perfectly when i call my stored procedure like below

```
User user = Context.SP_GetUserById(123456);
```

But i add a custom new column to stored procedure to return one more column like below

```
SELECT *, dbo.ConcatRoles(U.Id) AS RolesAsString
    FROM membership.[User] U
    WHERE Id = @id
```

Now when i execute it from SSMS new column called RolesAsString appear in result.
To work this on entity framework i added a new property called RolesAsString to my User class like below.

```
public partial class User
    {
        public string RolesAsString{ get; set; }
    }
```

But this field isnt filled by stored procedure when i call it.
I look to the Mapping Detail windows of my SP_GetUserById there isnt a mapping on this window. I want to add but window is read only i cant map it. I looked to the source of edmx cant find anything about mapping of SP.

How can i map this custom field?

Comment: First of all - **do not** call your stored procedures `sp_(something)` - that naming is reserved for Microsoft. Second of all - don't do a `SELECT * FROM...`  in your stored proc...

Comment: thanks for your comment, why u say don't call "select *" means write all column name like "select Id,Name,Email,...." ?

Comment: Yes - it safeguards you from extra fields coming back when fields are added to DB, which could break your DAL because it doesn't expect those fields. Never use `SELECT *` **anywhere**. Now, onto the question - did you update the function import in the model browser?

Comment: yes i update it on model browser but nothing happen. I also read that Entity Framework don't look to the partial classes so that it doesn't map "RolesAsString" column to entity property.

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? I have the exact same situation going on and am wondering if there is a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a complex type for the SP instead of using the partial class.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property to the User entity in the model browser.  It might work if defined in the model, not as a partial class... or, in the end, the simplest may be have it return to an entity, and convert the SP result into the User result, as a last resort.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread but I encountered this exact issue today.

One difference is that I haven't imported the SP into the dbContext but chose to use SQLQuery to return a list of Contact entities.

```
var allContacts = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Contacts> 
("CRM.GetAllContactsForCustomer @customerID, param1).ToList();
```

Like TS I had created a partial Class to hold an extra property that the SP would return.

```
public partial class Contacts
{
    public EnumContactOrigin ContactOrigin { get; set; }
}
```

This property does NOT get filled when executing the SP, same as when you do so with an imported SP in the dbContext.

For some reason I came up with the idea to create a wrapper class for Contacts to hold that extra property.

```
public class ExtendedContacts : Contacts
{
    public new EnumContactOrigin ContactOrigin { get; set; }
}
```

And guess what, it works! ContactOrigin does now get filled correctly.

```
var allContacts = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ExtendedContacts> 
("CRM.GetAllContactsForCustomer @customerID, param1).ToList();
```

In my case I'm ok with it being a wrapper class as I only use the list of contacts to show in a grid.

I would love to know though **why** this works? And if there is another way of retrieving extra properties into Contacts without the need of this ExtendedContacts class.